# PDF of an equation

Tags: probability

I have this equation: $y = \exp(x+1) + 2$ and I want to formulate the relative probability density function (pdf) $f_x (x)$. I am kind of confused right now, I know that it is an easy question.

Thank you

Comment: To write $f_x(x)$ if you mean $f_X(x)$ is to miss the point: there is a reason why the latter notation is used.

Comment: "PDF of an equation". A random variable can have a PDF, or a probability distribution can be determined by a PDF. But equations do not have PDF's. You must be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF needs to have certain features. (1) Non-negative over the entire domain, (2) area under the curve = 1, (3) area under the curve between $a,b$ $\in X$ is the probability of that interval.

In this case, it seems your answer is not far. Define an interval for your domain then divide $f_X(x)$ by its integral.